# Display content from multiple json on to a single div using ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my scenario. I have 3 separate json objects. I want to have all the 3 object values to be displayed in a single div. i.e (first values of imageList, headingList and priceList in first div and similarly second). I am trying to use ng-repeat like the one shown below. But it shows an error. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

```
<div ng-controller="bannerController">
    <div ng-repeat="image in imageList, heading in headingList, price in priceList">
        <div style="background-image: url({{image.url}}); width: 1000px; height: 320px;">
             <h1>{{heading.title}}</h1>

            <p>{{price.price}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below are the index.html and script.js

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Angular Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="bannerController">
            <div ng-repeat="image in imageList">
                <div style="background-image: url({{image.url}}); width: 1000px; height: 320px;">
                        <h1>{{heading.title}}</h1>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('bannerController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.imageList = [{
        url: 'some Url 1'
    }, {
        url: 'some url 2'
    }];

    $scope.headingList = [{
        title: 'Title',
        subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    }, {
        title: 'Title',
        subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    }];

    $scope.priceList = [{
        price: 2
    }, {
        price: 3
    }];
});
```

Comment: why dont you make the composite JSON object which contains imageList, headingList, & priceList, then try to use ng-repeat on the composite object

Comment: @saubar The problem is each content is coming from three different REST Urls. So I had to do it this way. Is there an alternative?

Comment: In every case all have same length ?

Comment: Yes all priceList, headingList and imageList has the same length. What I gave you is a mini version of the problem but actually these 3 individual objects are themselves composite json.

Comment: ok I have created a plunker for you.

Comment: @Kaushik let me know is it working or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get values by using `$index` property of ng-repeat.

[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/agHUCnbkEjUa50cLBvvy?p=preview)